How can I use LEA algorithm with JCE API?
I can do with LEAEngine directly.
final var engine = new LEAEngine();
final var cipher = new PaddedBufferedBlockCipher(CBCBlockCipher.newInstance(engine), p);
final var params = _ParametersWithIVTestUtils.newRandomInstanceOfParametersWithIV(
        null, ks, cipher.getUnderlyingCipher()
);

But I failed to work with the standard JCE API.
Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());
final var transformation = "LEA/CBC/PKCS5Padding";
final var cipher = Cipher.getInstance(transformation, "BC");


with the following error message.
Caused by: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: No such algorithm: LEA/CBC/PKCS5Padding
    at java.base/javax.crypto.Cipher.getInstance(Cipher.java:758)
    at java.base/javax.crypto.Cipher.getInstance(Cipher.java:646)

What can I do?

At the moment LEA seems to be implemented only in the low-level API and no JCE compatible provider seems to be implemented yet, see release notes for 1.70, sec. 2.12.3. You apparently already have a corresponding issue filed (#1880).
